# Displaying Data from a Join in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I am using a simple join to pull data from two databases. This is the join in the model:

```
function com_control(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $this->db->join('posts', 'comments.entry_id = posts.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result;
}
```

My desired method of display is going to be in a table so I am starting out to use like this:

```
foreach($comm_control as $row){

   $this->table->add_row(
   $row->entry_id,
   $row->comments.id,
   $row->comment,
   $row->title             
   );      
}//end of foreach
```

**My problem is the display of data from comments.id.** What is the proper format to add the comment.id into the table rows?  I need the ID from both tables for display, edit and delete further on in the table. The only display I get at this time for "comment.id" is the word id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display the column heading differently than 'id'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I think what you need to do is set an alias for the id field in the comments table:

```
function com_control() {
    $this->db->select('entry_id, comments.id AS comment_id, comment, title');
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $this->db->join('posts', 'comments.entry_id = posts.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result;
}
```

Then you can reference the comments.id field as simply $row->comment_id:

```
$this->table->set_heading('Entry ID', 'Comment ID', 'Comment', 'Title');

foreach ($comm_control as $row ) {
    $this->table->add_row(
        $row->entry_id,
        $row->comment_id,
        $row->comment,
        $row->title             
    );      
}

echo $this->table->generate();
```

Actually if the column 'id' is unique to the comments table, then you could just use $row->id; the problem arises when you are joining tables that both have a column named the same; it becomes ambiguous and the computer won't know what you're referencing.

Comment: Ah the problem is not the headings, the problem is when I retreive the data, the data in the "$row->comments.id " columm only outputs the word "ID".  SO basically I am asking if $row->comments.id is proper in this situation.  I think I will define the data I want more specifically in the database call

Comment: I solved my problem by renaming the duplicate fields of the database. Thanks guys

Comment: Awesome! And I just changed my answer that actually would have solved that without the db change lol

Comment: Well In would still like to know what is the proper method of displaying the ambiguous data.  Can that be done in the add row array?  Obviously my way was wrong

Comment: I checked the docs and spent a little while hacking away at it, and I'm pretty sure that the only way is to use an alias in the SELECT. So I'm going to call that the 'proper' way!