# Codeigniter: How to get data from id using two table by passing an id

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, crud

I have two join tables; parent and student. I have to update both tables from one button click. For that, I want to write a function "get data by id". I managed to write that code only for one table.

### **How do you write the following code if I want to get data from two tables? if p_id (parent id) is the foreign key?**

Model

```
   function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from('student');
    $this->db->where('p_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller

```
public function ajax_edit($id)
{
    $data = $this->Model_Action->get_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Data from a Join in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702030/displaying-data-from-a-join-in-codeigniter)

Comment: No, That's not the same, They are not passing an id.  I want to pass an id

Comment: passing id means it's just `where` condition what else difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*')
    $this->db->from('student');
    $this->db->join('parent','student.p_id=parent.p_id');
    $this->db->where('student.p_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think you are looking for this. I use a sample from your code:

```
   function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from('student');
    $this->db->join('table_b', 'student.p_id=table_b.p_id');
    $this->db->where('student.p_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Actually you can find more [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)